# Macbook: Flashing Folder with Question Mark At Startup

Tags: hardware, hard-drive, macbook-pro, startup, disk-utility

So, I've been hearing a clicking sound coming from my macbook for about a week now. The last few days the system has just been locking itself up when I try to type anything.

Now, at startup I see this:

[image]

I'm assuming that the clicking was "the click of death" and my hard drive is fried. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the most likely scenario.

Have you tried booting from a system disc? I'd recommend doing that, and then running Disk Utility and see what it says about the drive.

Comment: Thanks Dori, I've had this sucker for a long time and for the life of me, can't remember where my system disk is. I think it's time to retire this bad boy.

Answer (score 1):

not necessary:)

your mac just cannot where your OS is,

check here and if not helps, reformat HDD and install fresh OS

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1440

Comment: Thanks Stalker, I had my HDD tested and one of the arms is right off it's rocker

Comment: According to that link, the first thing to try is "Start up from a system software CD or DVD, and repair your disk using Disk Utility." Boy, that sounds [kinda familiar](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/macbook-flashing-folder-with-question-mark-at-startup/2706#2706)…

Answer (score 0):

My MacBook is an older one - OSX 10.5.8 . It has had the "folder of death" problem twice recently.  The first time I tried all the "fixes" recommended but to no avail.  I did not attempt wiping the HDD. I put it aside for a couple of weeks and was surprised to have it come good after that. Today it went bad again.  The clicking noise sounded like the HDD was stuck somehow.  So I gave it a thump on my knee and it booted normally.  I don't know if this cure is repeatable or works in all cases but for me it put off the inevitable trip to the Apple store for a while.